# InstallShield not all options available

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2015, installshield

I am trying to add vc_redist.x86 to InstallShield project but don't see those addition drop-down menus in solution explorer. However,when I create just a single InstallShield project those menus are available. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and Install Shield Limited Edition.

If you have other suggestions how I can make program install vc_redist.x86 I will be glad to hear them.

Thank you.

[Menus available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQOXk.png)

[Menus not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9HIo.png)